# How to stretch content horizontally inside a div so that it occupy evenly all the space?

Tags: html, css

Here's some HTML.

```
<div id = "header">
  <div id = "menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">Browse</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And, here's some CSS

```
#menu
{
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
}

#menu li a
{
 display: block;
 background-color: #999999;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 30px; 
 text-align: center;   
}
```

The above HTML and CSS give 4 rectangles. I'd like to have those rectangles to be evenly stretched horizontaly inside the the **menu div**.

Each time I try, I either get free space after **About rectangle** (i.e. the last rectangle) or get the About box flow to the next line.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
#menu li a
{  
 float:left;
 width:25%;
}

#menu li
{
 display:inline;   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BPyUB/

Comment: I still get a lot of space after the last rectangle. Is there any way to stetch them evenly from left to right.

Comment: @Richard77 that's just because of the 80% on the li - if you change that to 100%, or add margin:0px auto; to the li - it should be fine...